# in R how to efficiently check values of columns in dataframe to be ALL Zeros

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a dataframe like below:

```
      Profit                 Title MonthText OCT JAN AUG SEP APR MAR MonthInd

13 -11821431     Alone in the Dark       JAN   0   1   0   0   0   0        1
21  78114471     Are We There Yet?       JAN   0   1   0   0   0   0        1
27  19944017               Be Cool       MAR   0   0   0   0   0   1        1
28  13351350           Beauty Shop       MAR   0   0   0   0   0   1        1
29  18508485 Because of Winn-Dixie       FEB   0   0   0   0   0   0        0
38  47192859             Boogeyman       FEB   0   0   0   0   0   0        0
```

I wanted to change the MonthInd for the whole dataframe based on the values of the columns OCT JAN AUG SEP APR MAR

So if any of the column values (OCT JAN AUG SEP APR MAR) is 1 then MonthInd = 0 else all of the column values (OCT JAN AUG SEP APR MAR) is 0 then MonthInd = 1

I tried row by row and this is what I would like to be apply to run this test : For example for row 1 ,

```
(all(test[1,c(4:9)] == 0 ) )
```

But I would like to apply it to all the rows in test without doing a for-loop for n rows

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your interest is in a row-by-row result for `MonthInd` and that you are promising that the values will be 0 or positive

```
test[ , "MonthInd"] <- 
      rowSums( test[ , c('OCT','JAN', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'APR', 'MAR')] ) > 0

#----
> test
      Profit                 Title MonthText OCT JAN AUG SEP APR MAR MonthInd
13 -11821431     Alone in the Dark       JAN   0   1   0   0   0   0     TRUE
21  78114471     Are We There Yet?       JAN   0   1   0   0   0   0     TRUE
27  19944017               Be Cool       MAR   0   0   0   0   0   1     TRUE
28  13351350           Beauty Shop       MAR   0   0   0   0   0   1     TRUE
29  18508485 Because of Winn-Dixie       FEB   0   0   0   0   0   0    FALSE
38  47192859             Boogeyman       FEB   0   0   0   0   0   0    FALSE
```

The other option would to be running `apply` with a anonymous function using `any ( ... == 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to compare for rows, we can loop over the columns, compare with 0 to get ta `list` of `logical` vectors which we `Reduce` to a single logical vector with `&` and coerce to binary with `as.integer`.  This should be efficient.

```
test$MonthInd <- as.integer(!Reduce(`&`, lapply(test[, 4:9], `==`, 0)))
test$MonthInd
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Or it could be

```
as.integer(Reduce(`&`, lapply(test[4:9], `==`, 0)))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

---

The title says to `efficiently check values in column`.  In that case, convert the columns 4:9 logical matrix and then do `colSums`

```
colSums(test[, 4:9]==0)==nrow(test)
#  OCT   JAN   AUG   SEP   APR   MAR 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or use the negation

```
!colSums(test[, 4:9]!=0)
#  OCT   JAN   AUG   SEP   APR   MAR 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
      summarise_each(funs(all(.==0)), OCT:MAR)
#   OCT   JAN  AUG  SEP  APR   MAR
#1 TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: what i want is to have MonthInd to equal 1 if all the values in OCT,JAN,AUG,SEP,APR,MAR = 0 else 1

Comment: @EB  It is in the first part of my answer with `Reduce`.  I got distracted by your title